# coffeescript promise recursion chain issue

Tags: promise, coffeescript

My Initial data is like

```
[{"id":1,"type":"value","pid":"123"},
 {"id":2,"type":"value1","pid":"451"},
 {"id":3,"type":"value3","pid":"132"}
]
```

Now based on the `type==value1` I will recursively call a function which will give me `subset_data` for that element `pid` and continue like that.

Eventually the data will look something like this

```
[    
    {"1":{"type":"value","pid":"123"}}, ## transformed id as root key  
    {"2":{"type":"value1","pid":"451", ## make recursive function call and populate some subset_data for `pid=451`
          "subset_data":[
              {"4":{"type":"value","pid":"1234"},
              {"5":{"type":"value1","pid":"321",## make recursive function call and populate some subset_data for `pid=321`
                "subset_data":[
                  {...},
                  {...}
                 ]
               }
              },
              {"6":{"type":"value2","pid":"111"}
            ]
         }
     },
        
    {"3":{"type":"value3","pid":"132"}}
   ]
```

I have tried couple of function

```
get_datas = (id) ->
     get_data(id)
        .map (data) ->
            if data.type == "value1"
              get_datas(_.get(data,"pid"))
                .then (subdatas) ->
                  return _.set(
                    {},
                    [data.id, 'subset_data'],
                    subdatas
                  )
            _.zipObject([data.id], [ _.omit(data, 'id')])
```

This gives only this

```
[  
    {"1":{"type":"value","pid":"123"},
    {"2":{"type":"value1","pid":"451"},
    {"3":{"type":"value3","pid":"132"}}
   ]
```

Unable to add the `subdatas` to `data` . Not sure how to embed them to the return.

The other way i tried for testing

```
get_datas = (id) ->
     get_data(id)
        .map (data) ->
            if data.type == "value1"
              return get_datas(_.get(data,"pid"))                     
            _.zipObject([data.id], [ _.omit(data, 'id')])
```

This gives all nested data but without key(expected) like below

```
[
  [
    [
     {}
     {}
     {}
    ]
   {}
   {}
  ]
 {}
 {}
]
```

Comment: `->` is not JavaScript.

Comment: The desired output data structure is not clear.

Comment: My bad I should have mentioned `coffeescript`

Comment: You don't have return, in second variant, all you return is function not a value.

Comment: @Yaroslav not sure I have followed you `return get_datas(_.get(data,"pid"))  ` this will return the  list of subset_data elements `[{},{},{}]` . I tried `return _.set( {},[data.id,"subset_data"], get_datas(_.get(data,"pid")) ) ` but this is giving promise issue `{ "isFulfilled": false, "isRejected": false }`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the desired structure in the following manner for synchronous data retrieval.

```coffee
get_datas = (id) ->
  get_data(id).map ({ id, data... }) -> 
    data.subset_data = get_datas(data.pid) if data.type == 'value1'
    { [id]: data }
```

I've added this because in your question it looks like `get_data` is an synchronous function, in which case there is no need for `get_datas` to be asynchronous.

If `get_data` does turn out to be asynchronous, then `get_datas` will also be asynchronous as a consequence. This makes the above slightly more complex, but in general not that much changes.

```coffee
get_datas = (id) ->
  Promise.all (await get_data(id)).map ({ id, data... }) ->
    data.subset_data = await get_datas(data.pid) if data.type == 'value1'
    { [id]: data }
```

Note that `data.subset_data =`  does not mutate the original array element because `data...` is collecting all remaining properties in a new object. Since the second variant is asynchronous you should also make sure to `await` the result.